# JAXB Duplicate class renaming

Tags: java, maven, xsd, jaxb

Hi I wonder if anyone can help me. I have got two .xsd schema files orderservice-order.xsd and order.xsd each of which name an element type of "order".

## order.xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       targetNamespace="http://xml.xxxxxxxx.com/order"  
<xs:element name="order">
   <xs:complexType>
       <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="client" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
                   more elements here
      </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

## orderservice-order.xsd

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
       targetNamespace="http://xml.xxxxxxxx.com/order"  

<xs:element name="order">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="orderNumber" type="xs:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
                more elements here
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

## jaxbBindings.xjb

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="../XSD/v1.0/Representation/orderservice-order.xsd">
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='order']/xs:complexType">
        <jxb:class name="OSOrder" />
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

When I come to create the Java source for these schema files I am obviously getting a class name clash on the Order class.

I've created  a jaxb bindings .xjb file to rename the generated Order class name from the orderservice-order.xsd.

However I still get the following error

```
...XSD/v1.0/Representation/orderservice-order.xsd; lineNumber: 69;  columnNumber: 15; 'order' is already defined
```

It doesn't appear to be a problem with the XPATH in the .xjb file. If I rename the element in orderservice-order.xsd to say orderNew and change the xpath to

```
node="//xs:element[@name='orderNew']/xs:complexType"
```

there is obviously no name clash but the class IS renamed to 'OSOrder'

It's as if there is some pre-validation of the schema files PRIOR to the bindings file rename kicking in. I've tried turning off various jaxb/maven settings such as strict validation etc etc but to no avail.

Anybody seen this before and know a way to fix it??? By the way I don't control the content of the schema files.

Thank You

I'm using the maven plugin jaxb2-maven-plugin version 1.3 and jaxb version 2.0 running on Java 7.

## maven config

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Representations</id>
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaDirectory>XSD/v1.0/Representation</schemaDirectory>
                        <packageName>com.xxxxxxxxx.xml.representation.v1</packageName>
                        <bindingDirectory>XSD/v1.0/Representation</bindingDirectory>
                        <outputDirectory>src/main/generated-sources</outputDirectory>
                        <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxb/.representation</staleFile>
                        <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your JAXB bindings you can specify bindings for each file if you need and for each file rename the class as you want to resolve conflicts.

Here's an example :

```
<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="order.xsd">
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='order']">
        <jxb:class name="Order" implClass="Order"/>
    </jxb:bindings> 
</jxb:bindings>

<jxb:bindings schemaLocation="orderservice-order.xsd">
    <jxb:bindings node="//xs:element[@name='order']">
        <jxb:class name="OSOrder" implClass="OSOrder"/>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

Here's the documentation : http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html

### EDIT

I managed to reproduce the problem on my side.
The problem is the target namespace :

```
targetNamespace="http://xml.xxxxxxxx.com/order"
```

You have the same target namepace in both XSD.
So you define the type `order` twice in the same namespace which is not possible.
If you change the target namespace, you won't have the problem anymore.

Example for `orderservice-order.xsd`, I changed the target namespace into :

```
targetNamespace="http://xml.xxxxxxxx.com/orderservice-order"
```

I don't have the problem anymore.

Comment: Hi Michael Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately I've already tried this  (please see my jaxb binding file) The problem seems to be that the schema files are somehow validated prior to the class rename happening. I've tried your example of naming both classes but still get the same problem

Comment: I changed a couple things compared to what you did. First, I changed the XPATH pattern so it identify all the elements named "Order". Second, I added `implClass="Order"` so the implementation class name is forced to the name I provided according to JAXB documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html)

Comment: Yes I noticed that and tried your example but still get the same validation error. Also I think the classes map to complex types so the XPath should be `//xs:element[@name='order']/xs:complexType` but this doesn't work either. As a test I have tried removing one of the .xsd files to stop the clash and the xpath I am using then happily renames the class. I've noticed that the xjc command does do some validation but even using the -nv (no validation) parameter makes no difference. Maybe it's something to do with the maven plugin??